# Inseparable finite extensions a field with non zero characteristic.

Tags: field-theory

Suppose K is a field with characteristic p which is not a perfect field.

Then how do we prove that there does exist an irreducible polynomial which is not separable.

I have no idea how to proceed for this.what all i know is if K is a finite field then every irreducible polynomial is separable.

any hint/suggestion would be appreciated :)

Comment: If $K=F_p(t)$, then $x^p-t$ is irreducible and not separable.

Comment: Since you say in your third paragraph that such a polynomial does *not* exist if $K$ is finite, I assume you left out a condition on $K$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : edited :) thanks :)

Comment: @GerryMyerson : I see in case of $x^p-t$ but i would like to know how do we construct this?? Just intuition???

Comment: Dear Praphulla, I'm not sure if this is what you meant to imply, but it's *not* true that for every infinite field $K$ of char. $p$, there is an inseparable irreducible  polynomial in $K[x]$.  In general a field is called *perfect* if every irred. polynomial in $K[x]$ is separable.  As you note, all finite fields are perfect, but some infinite fields of char. $p$ are perfect too (e.g. all algebraically closed fields).  The field $K = \mathbb F_p(t)$ is the simplest example of a non-perfect field.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE : Oh yes, I meant to say K is not perfect field and with given conditions. I was little careless. Thanks for pointing out the error :)

Comment: Wait, if $K$ is not perfect, then by definition there is an irred. poly. which is inseparable...

Comment: @awllower : By perfect field i mean $K=K^p$

Comment: So you are trying to prove that, if $K\not=K^p$, then $K$ is not perfect? If so, then pick $t\in K-K^p$, and consider the polynomial $x^p-t$. If you are asking why we think of this, I am afraid that I cannot help then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Gerry Myerson let $K=F_p(t)$ and the sub-field $k=F(t^p)$ and finaly let the polynomial
$$P=x^p-t^p\in K[x]$$
so in $K[x]$ we have $P=(x-t)^p$ and since $t^i\not\in k,\ i=1,\ldots,p-1$ then $P$ is irreductible in $k[x]$ but it's not separable as $t$ is its root with multiplicity $p$ in $K$.